# C : system() call inside chroot

Tags: c, system, call, libraries, chroot

I have a program written in C, which runs chrooted, inside a jail, that makes some system calls e.g `system ( "ls" )`. The problem is that the program does not execute the system calls when I run it inside the jail. I have included all the necessary libraries of the executable ( found them with `ldd` bash command ), along with the bash executable ( `/bin/bash` ), and it's libraries ( also found with `ldd` ). It seems that something is missing. Does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: My Operating System is Ubuntu 10.04 64bit

Comment: Well, you're probably missing `/bin/ls`...

Comment: Run it under `strace -f` and see what fails.

Comment: Note that `system()` is not a "system call". To make it clear which you're referring to, it's best to refer to functions with their trailing (), as in `system()` or `exec()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) runs "/bin/sh -c <command>".

Copy `/bin/sh` to your chroot jail (or link it to /bin/bash) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

That might work, but the purpose of having a chroot is generally to prevent attackers from being able to execute arbitrary shell commands. Once you have put /bin/sh into a chroot jail you've eliminated any purpose to having the chroot jail in the first place.